# Protocol error when calling puppeteer.connect()

Tags: docker, google-chrome, websocket, puppeteer, caprover

I am using the basic approach as set out [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090055/4070848) to connect from a client docker container to any one of a number of chrome docker containers (in a docker swarm/service, potentially across several servers behind nginx, deployed using [CapRover](https://caprover.com/)).

In each chrome container I maintain a pool (just a simple array) of `browser` objects, and direct incoming requests to an appropriate `browser` as follows (very similar to the linked post):

```
import http from 'node:http';       // https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
import httpProxy from 'http-proxy'; // https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

const proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer({ ws: true });

// an array (pool) of pre-launched and managed browser objects...
const browsers = [ ... ];

http
  .createServer()
  .on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
      const browser = browsers[Math.floor(Math.random() * browsers.length)]; // in reality I don't just pick a browser at random
      const target = browser.wsEndpoint();
      proxy.ws(req, socket, head, { target });
  })
  .listen(3222);
```

The above is listening at `ws://srv-captain--chrome:3222` (communication is "internal" over the docker network between containers).

Then, in my client container, I connect to the common endpoint `ws://srv-captain--chrome:3222` as follows:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'; // https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer (using version 17.1.3 at time of posting this)
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://srv-captain--chrome:3222' });
} catch (err) {
    console.error('error connecting to browser', err);
}
```

This works really well, except that I am getting *occasional/inconsistent* errors like these when calling `puppeteer.connect()` in the client container above:

```
Protocol error (Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
Protocol error (Performance.enable): Target closed.
```

Almost always, if I simply try to connect again, the connection is made without further error, and at the first attempt.

I have no idea why the error is complaining that the `page has been closed` or `Target closed` since, at this point in the process, I'm not attempting to interact with any `page`, and I know from listening for `browser.on('disconnected'...)`, and also monitoring the chromium processes themselves, that each `browser` in the array is still working fine... none has crashed.

Any idea what's going on here?

---

**UPDATE after further testing**

Of course, in the client container we don't connect to a `browser` just for the sake of it, like in the above snippet, but to open a `page` and do some stuff with the `page`.  In practice, in the client container it's more like the following test snippet:

```
const doIteration = function (i) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // mimic incoming requests coming in at random times over a short period by introducing a random initial delay...
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 5000));
        // now actually connect...
        let browser;
        try {
            browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: `ws://srv-captain--chrome:3222?queryParam=loop_${i}` });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        // now that we have a browser, open a new page...
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // do something useful with the page (not shown here) and then close it..
        await page.close();
        // now disconnect (but don't close) the browser...
        browser.disconnect();
        resolve();
    });            
};

const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    promises.push( doIteration(i) );
}

try {
    await Promise.all(promises);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`error doing stuff`, err);
}
```

Each iteration above is being performed multiple times concurrently... I am using `Promise.all()` on an array of iteration promises to mimic multiple concurrent incoming requests in my production code.  The above is enough to reproduce the problem... the error doesn't happen on calling `puppeteer.connect()` with *every* iteration, just some.

So there seems to be some sort of interplay between opening/closing a `page` in one iteration, and calling `puppeteer.connect()` in another, despite closing the `page` and disconnecting the `browser` properly in each iteration?  This probably also explains the `Most likely the page has been closed` error message when calling `puppeteer.connect()` if there is some hangover relating to a `page` closed in another iteration... though for some reason this error occurs when calling `puppeteer.connect()`?

---

With the use of a pool of `browser` objects in the `browsers` array, and a docker swarm having multiple containers on multiple servers, each `upgrade` message could be received at a different container (which could even be on a different server) and could be routed to a different `browser` in the `browsers` array.  But I now think that this is a red herring, because in the further testing I narrowed the problem down by routing all requests to `browsers[0]` and also scaling the service down to just one container... so that the `upgrade` messages are always handled by the same container on the same server and routed to the same `browser`... and the problem still occurs.

---

Full stacktrace for the above-mentioned error:

```
Error: Protocol error (Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
    at CDPSession.send (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:281:35)
    at EmulationManager.emulateViewport (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/EmulationManager.js:33:73)
    at Page.setViewport (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1776:93)
    at Function._create (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Page.js:242:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Target.page (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Target.js:123:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async BrowserContext.pages (file:///root/workspace/myclientapp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:577:23)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I dug deeper and deeper into this problem, it become more and more apparent that I might not actually be doing anything fundamentally wrong, and that this might just be a bug in puppeteer itself.  So I reported those as [an issue over on puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8944)... and indeed, it is acknowledged as a bug for any version later than `15.5.0`, and is being fixed.  In the meantime, the workaround is to revert to puppeteer version `15.5.0` and to be careful when calling `browser.pages()` when concurrent connections are being used, because that might itself throw an error... but I understand that this too might be something that they can/will fix so that `browser.pages()` is more resilient to the presence of concurrent connections.